# Локально удалить и исключить обновление подмодуля

Tags: git, git-submodule

Проект, находящийся под СКВ Git включает в себя довольно большое число подмодулей. Обычно я выполняю следующие команды для получения актуального состояния:

1. Обновляю свой рабочий каталог

   ```
   $ git pull origin my_branch_name
   ```
2. Обновляю подмодули, в том числе инициализирую вновь добавленные:

   ```
   $ git submodule update --init --recursive
   ```

Проблема в том, что некоторые из подмодулей занимают довольно много места на диске и не используются мной (проект командный).

В связи с этим вопрос: есть ли возможность локально запретить гиту скачивать и обновлять определенный набор подмодулей? При этом хотелось бы все остальные подмодули обновлять также одной командой, т.е. не обновлять каждый конкретный подмодуль отдельно, т.к. они довольно часто обновляются.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого используйте [submodule deinit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-deinit-f--force--all--ltpathgt82308203) с путём к нужному подмодулю.

```
git submodule deinit path/to/submodule
```